# How to put a variable in a instance in the widget

Tags: php, functions, widgets, variables

I am creating a widget that handles order numbers. The basic structure is as follow:

```
// pretty generic widget functions
public function widget($args, $instance)
{
  $order_number = $instance['order_number'];
}
public function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
{
  $instance = $old_instance;
  $instance['order_number'] = strip_tags($new_instance['order_number']);
}


public function form($instance)
{
 if ($instance) {
    $order_number = esc_attr($instance['order_number']);
 }else {
    $order_number = '';
}
```

what I usually do is to **ask the user for the order number**. Like this:

```
<input name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('order_number'); ?>" 
type="text" value="<?php echo $order_number; ?>" />
```

but now I want to have a function that generates `order_number`. So my function is

```
function order_generator($email){
     .....
     return $order_num;
}
```

I want `order_num` to be set for the value of `order_number`.

how can I do this?

### Update #1

As requested by kaiserI try to explain this briefly.

**First Case:** 
I have a widget that prints the order number. This order number is entered by the user in an input field. As explained in the question, once the user enters an `order_number` it is saved in the instance and can be displayed later.

**Now this is the question:** I created a function called `order_generator` that dynamically creates the order number. The user doesn't have to enter the `order_number`. The function returns an integer named `$order_num`. I want to remove that input field which asked the user for order number and make the `order_num` value to `order_number` so I can display it.

Answer (score 1):

As far I understood you want to assign the order number like `$order_number = order_generator($email)` inside the widget class.

Yes, you can do it that way unless the `order_generator` is in another class. If you `order_generator` function is in another class then first you need to instantiate the class then call the method like `$instance_of_your_class->order_generator($email)`.

Hope that helps.